# cannot to add module to jpackage-created application

Tags: java, ssl, module, jpackage

i'm having a problem connecting my jpackage-created application to websocket endpoint. the cipher that is negotiated when running via my IDE is not available in the built image. it appears i'm encountering the issue described here: https://www.gubatron.com/blog/2019/04/25/solving-received-fatal-alert-handshake_failure-error-when-performing-https-connections-on-a-custom-made-jre-with-jlink/

i'm now trying to add `jdk.crypto.cryptoki` to my jpackage and not able to.

i first tried this

```
runtime {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    jpackage {
        imageName = 'MyCorpDashboard'
        installerName = 'MyCorpInstaller'
        appVersion = '0.1.0'
        if(org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
            jpackageHome = 'D:\\Java\\jdk-14' // Needs to be JDK 14
            installerType = 'exe'
            jvmArgs = ['-Djava.security.debug=access,stack',
                       '-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv2,TLSv1.2',
                       '-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose'
                       '--add-modules', 'jdk.crypto.cryptoki']
            imageOptions = ['--win-console', '--icon','src/main/resources/com/mycorp/ui/dashboard/icon_wh.ico']
            installerOptions = ['--win-per-user-install',
                            '--win-dir-chooser',
                            '--win-menu',
                            '--win-shortcut',
                            '--vendor', 'My Corp']
        } else if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().macOsX) {
            jpackageHome = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/' // Needs to be JDK 14
            imageOptions = ['--vendor', 'My Corp',
                            '--icon','src/main/resources/com/mycorp/ui/dashboard/icon_wh.icns']
        }
    }
}
```

but get

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.crypto.cryptoki not found
```

i also tried

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "jdk.crypto.cryptoki"]
}
```

and that did not work either.

how can i add this module so that it is packaged with my application?

Answer (score 0):

oi - right after posting i think i see it now, under runtime (after revisiting https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/)

```
runtime {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    modules = ['jdk.crypto.cryptoki']
    jpackage {
        imageName = 'MyCorpDashboard'
        installerName = 'MyCorpInstaller'
        appVersion = '0.1.0'
        if(org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
            jpackageHome = 'D:\\Java\\jdk-14' // Needs to be JDK 14
            installerType = 'exe'
            jvmArgs = ['-Djava.security.debug=access,stack',
                       '-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv2,TLSv1.2',
                       '-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose']
            imageOptions = ['--win-console', '--icon','src/main/resources/com/mycorp/ui/dashboard/icon_wh.ico']
            installerOptions = ['--win-per-user-install',
                            '--win-dir-chooser',
                            '--win-menu',
                            '--win-shortcut',
                            '--vendor', 'My Corp']
        } else if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().macOsX) {
            jpackageHome = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/' // Needs to be JDK 14
            imageOptions = ['--vendor', 'My Corp',
                            '--icon','src/main/resources/com/mycorp/ui/dashboard/icon_wh.icns']
        }
    }
}
```